# Finding number of eigen-values different from $0$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let be the following array of numerical data :
>
> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> Country/Type & Leisure & Leisure-work & work\\
> \hline
> Norway & 6 & 1 & 11\\
> Canada & 1 & 3 & 11\\
> Greece & 4 & 25 & 0\\
> France & 2 & 2 & 20\\
> \hline
> \end{array}$$
>
> We apply the Factor analysis
>
> Why is the number of eigen values different from $0$ at most equal to 2 ?

I thought first we were talking about finding eigen values of the data matrix but, thanks to @Bemte, I thought that was weird because it is not even a squared matrix.

I then did the variance matrix $V=\frac{1}{n}YY^t$ but it gived me the following matrix :

$$V=\begin{pmatrix}
25.148148 & 18.666667 & -62.092593\\
18.666667 & 28 & -53.666667\\
-62.092593 & -53.666667 & 157.37037
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is said not to have any eigen values [according to this online calculator](http://wims.unice.fr/~wims/en_tool~linear~matrix.en.phtml).

Comment: A non-square matrix does not have eigen-values... You might consider the values of the first three rows of your matrix $X$ and drop the last one, then the values would be $6,2,1$, yes. So either the claim that the number is two or your computation is false.

Comment: @Bemte I wonder wether it isn't on the variance matrix that I have to find the number of eigen values different rom $0$.

Comment: As I have no idea what $Y$ is, I can't really help you with that, sorry... However, $Y$ should better not be your $4 x 3$ data matrix, as otherwise you should NOT round the values (you will not get any/the right eigenvalues with rounded numbers...).

Comment: @Bemte $Y$ is the centered data